# Ansible AWX API call to register hostname in inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I am trying to make a post call to the AWX API in order to register the hostname IP into the inventory.
A normal curl request that works would look like this:

```
 curl -k -s --user "awx-user:awx-pwd" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://awx-api-url/api/v2/inventories/host_group_id/hosts/" --data '{ "name": "172.10.100.10", "description": "test-vm" }'
```

The playbook part that I am trying to use looks like this:

```
- name: Register host in AWX Inventory
  uri:
    url: "https://awx-api-url/api/v2/inventories/{{ host_group_id }}/hosts/"
    method: POST
    validate_certs: false
    user: "{{ api_awx_username }}"
    password: "{{ awx_pwd_api }}"
    return_content: true
    force_basic_auth: true
    status_code: [200, 202]
    body: '{"name": {{ guest_custom_ip }}, "description": {{ vm_hostname }}; }'
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
    body_format: raw
  register: reg_awx_inventory
```

The error I get is:

```
  "content": "{\"detail\":\"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)\\nPossible cause: trailing comma.\"}",
```

I double checked the message, but it doesn't seem to be an issue with the trailing comma, any ideas? Thx.

Comment: `'{"name": "{{ guest_custom_ip }}", "description": "{{ vm_hostname }}" }'` > you forgot to quote the values and introduced a weird semicolon. Or better yet, format your body as a YAML and let Ansible the magic.

Comment: Was doing something very stupid indeed, thanks for the heads-up :)